# Using variables from one entity into another in VHDL

Tags: entity, vhdl

I have a little question related to my VHDL code. I have to create a simulation for 1 bit of ALU. I created a D flip-flop and a Full Adder, and now I have to connect them with some simple logical gates. How can I do to use variables from this 2 entities to do this?

My code is:

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY D_flipflop IS PORT (
        D, Clock: IN STD_LOGIC;
        Q: OUT STD_LOGIC);
END D_flipflop;
ARCHITECTURE Behavior OF D_flipflop IS
    BEGIN
        PROCESS(Clock)
        BEGIN
        IF Clock'EVENT AND Clock = '0' THEN
            Q<= D;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
END Behavior;

ENTITY fa IS PORT (
        Ci, Xi, Yi: IN STD_LOGIC ;
        Ci1, Si: OUT STD_LOGIC) ;
END fa;

ARCHITECTURE Dataflow OF fa IS
    BEGIN
        Ci1 <= (Xi AND Yi) OR (Ci AND (Xi XOR Yi));
        Si <= Xi XOR Yi XOR Ci;
End Dataflow ;
```

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.7 Component instantiation statement *NOTE 2-The component instantiation statement may be used to imply a structural organization for a hardware design. By using component declarations, signals, and component instantiation statements, a given (internal or external) block may be described in terms of subcomponents that are interconnected by signals.* Signals not variables, instantiate design entities (entity declarations and a matching their architecture body) interconnected by signals. Also see 3. Design entities and configurations.

Comment: Neither of those entities use any variables, so you can't. Use signals instead.

Comment: And after this...?

Comment: "I have to" sounds like a homework assignment. I bet you have a book that tells you how you should approach this problem. Else look for a student's guide to VHDL or such.

Comment: That's true. But I don't have any book. :) It's ok... Thanks for help.